# Stack Exchange app not showing some icons

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app

As of February 13, 2020 the **Android version of Stack Exchange app** is not showing custom icons of Stack Exchange sites properly. It's showing a generic icon (the same as app icon) for all of them instead.

Is it a bug or is my Android system outdated?

Follow this link to see: [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/P59XJJMV/image.jpg)

*Info generated by app follows:*

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: D6633
- OS Version: 4.4.4 (n7_2Rw)

Comment: The app is not being maintained.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The site icons look just fine to me.